# How to find select multiple duplicates among two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database table `Inventory` with two columns `hospital_id` and `location_id` that interest me. Individually they can each have duplicates.

I want to find out `hospital_id`'s which have multiple `location_id`'s in ordered way

For example, these are my columns:

[image]

Output should be:

[image]

Comment: please post current and expected results as text

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Do you just want hospitals that appears more than once or hospital/locations pairs that appear more than once?

Comment: i want all hospital_ids with at least 2 duplicate rows as well as all location_id's with two duplicates together

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

As an alternative to Gordon's query, you could slightly modify the answer which @JuergenD and I gave initially:

```
SELECT hospital_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY hospital_id
HAVING COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT location_id) >= 1
ORDER BY hospital_id
```

A hospital which has any location in duplicate would have a total count which is greater than the `DISTINCT` count.

Comment: This was the first answer posted.

Comment: for mutiple location_id's i need to get whichever having corresponding hospital_id counts.

Comment: i want all hospital_ids with at least 2 duplicate rows as well as all location_id's with two duplicates together

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want duplicates of `hospital_id`/`location_id` pairs.  I'm not sure why you are only outputting the `hospital_id`, but you can do

```
select hospital_id
from t
group by hospital_id, location_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: think this is the only answer that will produce what the OP intended, others are missing the location grouping

Comment: @Tanner I think you jumped the gun by downvoting anyone.  At least my query does produce the correct output for the sample data given.

Comment: @Tanner . . . The question is ambiguous.  I happen to think that my interpretation is probably the intention of the OP, but the other answers are reasonable and not worthy of downvotes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no downvotes by me, thought my comments were sufficient to highlight my point

Comment: i want all hospital_ids with at least 2 duplicate rows as well as all location_id's with two duplicates together

Answer (score 1):

```
select hospital_id, count(location_id) as locationcount from tab2
group by hospital_id
having count(location_id) > 1
order by hospital_id
```

Comment: i want all hospital_ids with at least 2 duplicate rows as well as all location_id's with two duplicates together

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.hospital_id 
FROM (
    SELECT  hospital_id, 
            COUNT(location_id)
            location_count 
    FROM Inventory 
    GROUP BY hospital_id 
    HAVING COUNT(location_id) > 1 
) a ORDER BY hospital_id
```

Comment: i want all hospital_ids with at least 2 duplicate rows as well as all location_id's with two duplicates together

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES hospital_id --, location_id --if you need
FROM Inventory
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hospital_id, location_id ORDER BY location_id) = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
```

It will show all `hospital_id`s with at least 2 duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking like more locations for hospital and more hospital and locations?

```
;with cte as (
select hospital_id,'' locaation_id, count(location_id) as locationcount from tab2
group by hospital_id
having count(location_id) > 1

union all

select hospital_id, location_id, count(*) as cnt from tab2
group by hospital_id, location_id
having count(*) > 1
)
select * from cte order by hospital_id
```

In the select list from CTE you can select hospital_id only if you require

Answer (score 0):

```
select  hospital_id,
        location_id 
into #temp1 
from inventory 
where hospital_id in (
        select hospital_id 
        from inventory 
        group by hospital_id 
        having count(hospital_id)>1)
group by hospital_id,location_id 

select hospital_id 
from #temp1 
group by hospital_id 
having count(hospital_id)>1
```

Comment: And my code returns all `hospital_id` with more then one same `location_id`. Have you tried it?